# Locating an element by XPATH or Partial Link Text

Tags: html, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I've been trying to locate the element below:

```
<a class="bui-list-item bui-list-item--size-small " data-modal-header-async-url-param="changed_currency=1&amp;selected_currency=AED&amp;top_currency=1" href="/index.html?aid=378266&amp;label=bdot-Os1%2AaFx2GVFdW3rxGd0MYQS461500239550%3Apl%3Ata%3Ap1%3Ap22%2C563%2C000%3Aac%3Aap%3Aneg%3Afi%3Atikwd-334108349%3Alp9075160%3Ali%3Adec%3Adm%3Appccp%3DUmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YYriJK-Ikd_dLBPOo0BdMww&amp;sid=0046f3b8fc5eedc89ce89f8c85845319&amp;sb_price_type=total&amp;changed_currency=1&amp;selected_currency=AED&amp;top_currency=1">
<div class="bui-inline-container">
<div class="bui-inline-container__main">
U.A.E. Dirham
<div class="bui-traveller-header__currency">
AED
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Here's the full XPATH of the element:

```
/html/body/div[19]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a
```

I've tried to locate the element by its XPATH:

```
currency_element = webDriver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=_1fhoql6ro]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div"
                                                       "/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a[@data-modal-header-async-url-param="
                                                       "changed_currency=1&selected_currency=AED&top_currency=1")
currency_element.click()
```

But this gives me the following error:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string

I've tried to locate the element by partial link text and even link text but I don't know why nothing is working.

```
currency_element = webDriver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "selected_currency=AED")
currency_element.click()
```

The window has many currency options and I need to select the currency given in input by the user but I can't figure out how to use a formatted string with XPATH or locate by partial link text.

Answer (score 0):

@Kanji, since I do not have the full HTML code, the following options you can try. I have tried them all before putting them here:

1. By contains method on visible text - AED

   `//a//div[contains(text(), 'AED')]`
2. By attribute match for the `data-modal-header-async-url-param` attribute

   `//a[@data-modal-header-async-url-param = 'changed_currency=1&selected_currency=AED&top_currency=1']`
3. By partial match for the attribute

   `//a[contains(@data-modal-header-async-url-param,'AED')]`

The above XPath you can parameterize by using a variable instead of a hard-coded value of 'AED' which you can pass at run time based on the currency you want.

Let me know if it helps.